# Can Zam-Zam water turn ordinary water into Zam-Zam water?

Tags: islamic-basis

I've heard that, if even some droplets of Zam-Zam water is mixed with ordinary waters the mixture will have the qualities of Zam-Zam water. In fact, the ordinary water turns into Zam-Zam water if it is mixed with Zam-Zam water.

*Does this belief have any Islamic basis?*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I searched, I solely found a related issue of a tradition regarding the effect of the dropping Zam-Zam water in ordinary water in accordance with the research of a Japanese scientist. Consequently, perhaps it could be beneficial to some extent whereof nobody could found such a matter according to the traditions. Reading the below issue could be related to your inquiry somewhat.

According to the research of Dr. Masaaro Imoto, dropping one drop of Zam Zam water in ordinary water could change the ordinary water to Zam-Zam water which could has the quality of Zam-Zam water. (According to the report of Al-Alam channel).

---

**Reference.**

- [weblog24.com](http://weblog24.com/weblog/eerie/1131480)

Comment: Thanks, but can you present more details?

Comment: more details? about the research which has done by that Japanese scientist? if so, all right, I'll do it, otherwise as I stated, unfortunately I couldnt find more matter. (from the viewpoint of Islam)